# general submit javascript function in table

Tags: javascript, forms

I have specific html setup that looks like this

```
<table class="table">
<form action="" name="f_form" id="id_f_form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="f1" value="555">
    <tr onClick="javascript: submitform();">Block</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Where the javascript function `submitform()` looks like this

```
function submitform() {
    if (confirm("Do you want to proceed?")){
        document.f_form.submit();
    }
}
```

What I want is a general javascript function that works with every form and not only this form with the name="f_form". I really don't want to write a java function for each and every form :P.

Answer (score 1):

This will use jQuery as it's easier to bind an event on multiple element.

```
$("form").on('submit',function(){
    if(confirm("Do you want to proceed?")){
        $(this)[0].submit();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: don't forget if your using jQuery like this to use a `(function($){$(function(){ /* code here */ }})(jQuery)` wrapper to make sure it does not break anything / if jQuery is loaded in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters sort your HTML that is invalid HTML

Your code with valid required HTML, Body, head and DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
<form action="" name="f_form" id="id_f_form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="f1" value="555">
    <tr onClick="javascript: submitform();">Block</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

use it at https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

so for valid code it should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f_form" id="id_f_form" method="POST">
<table class="table">
    <tr onClick="submitform(this);"><td><input type="hidden" name="f1" value="555" />Block</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As for your script with valid HTML you make it really easy using jQuery

```
function submitform(e){ 
    if (confirm("Do you want to proceed?")){
        jQuery(e).parent('form').submit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but didn't get it to work. note that I want the clickable area to valid only for the <tr></tr> area not the entire table.

Comment: I don't know why that does not work. I have tested it in jsFiddle it would appear jQuery docs are wrong for `.parent( [selector] )`

Comment: As your clickable area the entire table is 1 cell so it will all be clickable however if you we're to have another row in above it that row would not be clickable.